# How do I write influx line protocol records to QuestDB using Python?

Tags: questdb

How can I send influx line protocol messages to QuestDB from python? Should I be using a library or should I write to the socket? The [node example](https://questdb.io/docs/develop/insert-data) looks like

```js
const net = require("net")

const client = new net.Socket()

const HOST = "localhost"
const PORT = 9009

function run() {
  client.connect(PORT, HOST, () => {
    const rows = [
      `trades,name=test_ilp1 value=12.4 ${Date.now() * 1e6}`,
      `trades,name=test_ilp2 value=11.4 ${Date.now() * 1e6}`,
    ]

    rows.forEach((row) => {
      client.write(`${row}\n`)
    })

    client.destroy()
  })

  client.on("data", function (data) {
    console.log("Received: " + data)
  })

  client.on("close", function () {
    console.log("Connection closed")
  })
}

run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python equivalent for the example looks something like the following:

```py
import time
import socket

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 9009

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

try:
  sock.sendto(('trades,name=test_ilp1 value=12.4 %d' % (time.time_ns())).encode(), (HOST, PORT))
  sock.sendto(('trades,name=test_ilp2 value=11.4 %d' % (time.time_ns())).encode(), (HOST, PORT))
except socket.error as e:
  print("Got error: %s" % (e))
sock.close()
```

Note that calling `time.time_ns()` inside the influx line message is optional, so you can omit it and the server will assign the system time as a timestamp for the row. For the format of incoming messages, you can find a reference on the [questdb influx docs](https://questdb.io/docs/reference/api/influxdb#syntax)

Answer (score 1):

There's now an official Python client for the QuestDB database:

```bash
python3 -m pip install questdb
```

Example:

```py
from questdb.ingress import Sender

with Sender('localhost', 9009) as sender:
    sender.row(
        'line_sender_example',
        symbols={'id': 'OMEGA'},
        columns={'price': 111222233333, 'qty': 3.5})
    sender.row(
        'line_sender_example',
        symbols={'id': 'ZHETA'},
        columns={'price': 111222233330, 'qty': 2.5})
```

Repo: https://github.com/questdb/py-questdb-client

Docs: https://py-questdb-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html